# Почему мой вывод крестика не проходит автотесты?

Tags: java, массивы

Крестик распечатывается, но проблема заключается в том, что код вообще не проходит автотесты. Подскажите что не так.

```
public class TwoDimensionalArray {

    public static final char SYMBOL = 'X';

    public static char[][] getTwoDimensionalArray(int size) {

        //TODO: Написать метод, который создаст двумерный массив char заданного размера.
        // массив должен содержать символ SYMBOL по диагоналям, пример для size = 3
        // [X,  , X]
        // [ , X,  ]
        // [X,  , X]

        String[][] cross = new String[size][size];
        for(int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                cross[i][j] = (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) ? "x" : " ";
                System.out.print(cross[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        return new char[0][0];
    }
}
```

Вот фото того как выглядит разница между тем что требуется и тем что получается у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так что у вас получается???

Comment: В консоле я вижу крестик из х, но все автотесты не проходят. И скрин показывает  что ожидается и что у меня. Т.е. символ [x] не передаётся

Comment: Тест проверяет возвращаемый массив, или то, что вы печатаете?

Comment: тесты проверяют массив

Answer (score 0):

Замените возвращаемое значение на

```
return cross;
```

Объявите массив как

```
char[][] cross = new char[size][size];
```

И кавычки при присвоении одинарные

```
... ? 'x' : ' ';
```

Проверено на https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler :

```
public class Main
{
    public static char[][] getTwoDimensionalArray(int size) {

        //TODO: Написать метод, который создаст двумерный массив char заданного размера.
        // массив должен содержать символ SYMBOL по диагоналям, пример для size = 3
        // [X,  , X]
        // [ , X,  ]
        // [X,  , X]

        char [][] cross = new char[size][size];
        for(int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                cross[i][j] = (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) ? 'x' : ' ';
                //System.out.print(cross[i][j]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }


        return cross;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         char [][] cross = getTwoDimensionalArray(3);
         for(int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(cross[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
         
    }
}
```

Comment: выдает ошибку. говорит что передано значение String[][], а должно быть char

Comment: Так и объявите массив как  `char[][] cross = new char[size][size];` - вы же должны выполнять соглашение о типе метода и согласовать внутренний тип с результатом

Comment: Не работает. сейчас вообще рисунок пропал. Сейчас это выглядит так: [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
[ , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
[NULL, , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
NULL, NULL,  , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
[NULL, NULL, NULL,  , NULL, NULL, NULL]
[NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL,  , NULL, NULL]
[X,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , X]

Comment: Я проверил на онлайн компиляторе.

Comment: Все равно ошибка. Не проходит автотесты. Х пропал совсем.

Comment: Вы можете видеть, что теперь массив создаётся и выдаётся наружу метода верно. Остальное - проблемы вашего взаимодействия с тестирующей системой.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoDimensionalArray {

    public static final char SYMBOL = 'X';

    public static char[][] getTwoDimensionalArray(int size) {

        //TODO: Написать метод, который создаст двумерный массив char заданного размера.
        // массив должен содержать символ SYMBOL по диагоналям, пример для size = 3
        // [X,  , X]
        // [ , X,  ]
        // [X,  , X]

        char[][] cross = new char[size][size];
        for(int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                if (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) {
                    cross[i][j] = 'X';
                } else {
                    cross[i][j] = ' ';
                }
                System.out.print(cross[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return cross;
    }
}
```